# Sharing an Ember Object between controllers with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to share a Ember object between different controllers in order to 'decorate' it with more information as you go through the app.

In a simple Ember app I would just do:

```
App.UserDetails = Ember.Object.extend({name: 'Darryl', age: 26 });

App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.UserDetails;
  }
});

App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.UserDetails;
  }
});
```

But I can't see I would organise this in Ember CLI

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use data persistence library like Ember Data, because it was designed for things like storing user details and there are tons of information how to do that, but you ask about sharing an object so:

You can use `Ember.Service`:

Details service:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    name: 'Darryl',
    age: 26
});
```

Rest:

```
App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  details: Ember.inject.service(),
  model: function () {
    return this.get('details');
  }
});

App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  details: Ember.inject.service(),
  model: function () {
    return this.get('details');
  }
});
```

Comment: No really sure Ember Data has anything to do with his question. +1 for Ember services though. This is exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: It has, because I think Services were designed for something else and Ember Data was is for storing data in application. Alternatively someone can use dependency injection in container I guess.

Comment: Ember Data was designed for _persisting_ data, not storing it. If the data he wants to store is ephemeral (which it seems like it might be), then Ember services are the perfect tool.

Comment: Okay, maybe I went little too far with my assumptions.

Comment: No big deal. :) Just throwing my opinion out there.

Comment: I'd say that if this is really all the OP wants to do, the case for making this into a service is weak. It's more typical for a service to have some persistent state, and for it to provides methods to do something or other. If it's merely a shared semi-global object, although there's no harm in making it into a server, what's the point?

Comment: Yeah, I'm well aware that `Ember.Service` for that is not the best solution.

Comment: Yes that's all I need, none of this data is getting saved anywhere, its just used at runtime. Thanks guys

Answer (score -1):

The same thing can be done like this,

```
//userdetails.js 
export default Ember.Object.create({
  name: 'Darryl',
  age: 26 
});
```

In your Routes,

```
//details.js
import obj from 'path/userdetails';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
    return obj;
  }
});

//account.js
import obj from 'path/userdetails';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
    return obj;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please specify the reason for the downvote, so i can correct my knowledge.